# convert myAdapter synthetic to viewbinding

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

i'm confused, how can i update my adapter views from synthetic to viewbinding!
here is my code, how define viewbinding to viewHolder?

```
class PlayersListAdapter(
    var items: ArrayList<MatchPlayer>
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        val inflate: View =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_team_player, parent, false)

        return MatchSubstitutionHolder(inflate)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        viewHolder.itemView.lblPlayerName.text = "name"

    }

    class MatchSubstitutionHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        var view = itemView
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's so easy like define viewbinding in fragment or activity

```
class PlayersListAdapter(
    var items: ArrayList<MatchPlayer>
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<TeamPlayersListAdapter.MatchSubstitutionHolder>() {

  

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MatchSubstitutionHolder {

        val binding= ItemTeamPlayerBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)

        return MatchSubstitutionHolder(binding)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: MatchSubstitutionHolder, position: Int) {

        viewHolder.binding.lblPlayerName.text = "name"

    }

    class MatchSubstitutionHolder(val binding: ItemTeamPlayerBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size

    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is best for you

```
class PlayersListAdapter(var items: ArrayList<MatchPlayer>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<TeamPlayersListAdapter.MatchSubstitutionHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MatchSubstitutionHolder {
        val binding = ItemTeamPlayerBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return MatchSubstitutionHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: MatchSubstitutionHolder, position: Int) {
        viewHolder.bind(position)
    }

    class MatchSubstitutionHolder(val binding: ItemTeamPlayerBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(position: Int) {
            val matchPlayer = items[position]
            binding.lblPlayerName.text = "name"
        }
    }
}
```